# How do I attach a carpet runner down a staircase with a turn in it?

Tags: carpet, stairs

I need to install a carpet runner down a staircase.  This is a typical installation with the brass bars in the corner between the tread and riser to hold it down.  The difficulty is that the staircase has a turn near the bottom where the steps are triangular in shape.

What is the best practice in such an installation?

Comment: Yes, there is.  It's a simple staircase with a corner turn - 2 Straight steps from the main floor, three triangles making a 90 degree turn, and then 10 up to the second floor.  

Obviously, I can't do this in a single run -- There are triangular pieces that need to be cut out.  I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Mock it up full size, in something cheap like construction paper. Then you can cut and tape and rearrange to your hearts content until you see the pattern you need.

Comment: I was able to find about 30 different ways to install a runner on a straight staircase, and 0 on how to install on a non-straight staircase.  Seems to be a carpet installers closely guarded secret.

Comment: Yeah, straight is easy.  Secure at top, roll it down, attach bars.

Comment: From the limited info I could find, it sounds like you're going to be cutting and seaming, or folding and tucking.  Is is a solid color runner, or a fancy one with a pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases the bars are cosmetic.Each tred/riser set is done individually and stapled or tack stripped in place.I believe this is done for liability,if a bar came loose the carpet would slide.